# Is there a way to unexecute script in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have an extension that injects a script to a page that listens to certain events and then sends the data back to the background page.

The extension is restarted every n minutes, and so it happens that it injects the script again and again into that page.

Thus two or more exact same script copies are running at the same time and this behavior also leads to errors.

Is there are a way to stop executed scripts on a page, like a reverse of "chrome.tabs.executeScript" function, which I could call before injecting another instance of that script?

Comment: You could set a flag in your script. Execute the code when the flag is `true` and at `n - 0.5` minutes set flag to `false`.

Comment: Send some `"test"` message to the page first, and in the content script `sendResponse(true)` for that message. Check the response in the background script and if it's `undefined` it would mean no content script is running.